# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: cartItems is not defined"

Tags: vue.js

so i rendering succusfully products , now i want to add the product id to the cart array however once i clicked on the add button it gives me this error 
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: cartItems is not defined"
hopefully u can give me a hint on how to fix the problem
thnak you so much

this is the code

```
   <template>
  <main>
    <div class="margin"></div>
    <div class="shopTitle">
      <h1>Shop</h1>
    </div>
    <section>

        <div v-if="show" class="products">
          <div class="product" v-for="product in filteredProducts" :key="product.productId">
            <div class="imgproduct"></div>

            <div class="productDetails">
              <div>
                <h1>{{product.productTitle}}</h1>
              </div>
              <div>
                <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>{{product.productPrice}}</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <i @click="addToCart(product)" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </section>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      products: [
        {
          id: 1,
          productTitle: "Shoes",
          productImg: "../assets/ProductOne.png",
          productPrice: "246$",
          category: "Shoes"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          productTitle: "Suits",
          productImg: "../assets/ProductOne.png",
          productPrice: "246$",
          category: "Suits"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          productTitle: "Bags",
          productImg: "../assets/ProductOne.png",
          productPrice: "246$",
          category: "Bags"
        }
      ],
      selectedCategory: "All",
      show: true,
      cartItems: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addToCart(itemToAdd) {
      // Add the item or increase qty
      let itemInCart = this.cartItems.filter(item => item.id === itemToAdd.id);
      let isItemInCart = itemInCart.length > 0;

      if (isItemInCart === false) {
        this.cartItems.push(itemToAdd);
      } else {
      }
      console.log(cartItems)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: The line producing this error is `console.log(cartItems)`? That's because `cartItems` indeed does not exist; you want `console.log(this.cartItems)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(cartItems)
```

should be

```
console.log(this.cartItems)
```